# how to maintain unique size of a polygon in both orientations?

Tags: android, opengl-es

i am rendering a cube using openGLES1.0.if i change orientation(Landscape to portrait and viceversa)of device,cube size is changing.in portrait mode,cube size is big,where as in Landscape orientation size became low.i want to make it of unique size in both orientations.please help me.Thanks in advance